# Android data directory

Tags: android

Is it possible to provide files int the data/data directory of an android application on install? If so, where would I put these files in my project?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to provide files int the data/data directory of an android application on install?

Not automatically. You are welcome to package files as assets or raw resources and copy them to `getFilesDir()` on the first run of your application.